# Implementation of datatypes in Haskell?

Tags: data-structures, term-rewriting, interactive-proof-systems

In Haskell, are datatypes converted to the "Church encoding" i.e. folding the data type.  For example, given

```
data N = Z | S N
```

in Haskell, it can be converted to its church encoding by

```
foldN Z z s = z
foldN (S n) z s = s (foldN z s n)
```

Where if we do foldN m, we get the church encoding:

```
\z s . s (  .... s n ... )
```

In Proofs and Types, Girard shows how this works for any inductive datatype.  There are two questions I have: (1) is this actually how Haskell treats datatypes and (2) what is the equivalent construction for coinductive datatypes.

Comment: What I mean by question (1) is: does Haskell use this translation into System F in any way?  Does any language use such a translation?  It seems that there would be efficiency issues with doing this.

Comment: Haskell is a language, not a specific compiler or interpreter, so different implementations could do different things. GHC does not do this. As you stated, there would be efficiency issues.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: No implementation of Haskell to my knowledge has ever represented datatypes as church encodings.

I believe that church-style encodings (or variants such as Scott encodings) work equally well for coinductive types.